# delay adding class to elements with setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

So I have a bunch of div elements that I want to add a class to, so it trigger a transition -- but I want the class to be added 1 at a time, not simultaneously so the animation appears 1 at a time.

This is how my javascript looks like.

```
var campaignInfo = document.querySelectorAll(".campaign-info-container");

setTimeout(function(){
    for(i=0; i<=campaignInfo.length;i++){
        campaignInfo[i].classList.add("campaign-container-slide");
        console.log(campaignInfo[i]);
    };  
}, 2000);
```

so basically I use querySelectorAll so it captures all the divs with that class, which shows up when I `console.log()` it.

But regardless the classes are not added with a delay.. I'm not sure how I can add an iteration to the milliseconds `2000 * i` if `i` is only defined inside the loops. I tried creating a `var counter;` outside the `setTimeout`, and increment it inside the loop with `counter++`, but the delay still won't work.

Also, I'm getting this error "Can't read property classList of undefined.

Thanks guys. Oh and please no jQuery :)

EDIT:

Thanks for the solution! :)

So does the `setInterval` work like a loop in your case?

Because I want this interval to occur whenever I click on a button, but removed when I exit out of the frame. So I added the below to remove the class from the elements. But I use a `for` loop instead..

```
for(i=0; i<=campaignInfo.length; i++){ 
  campaignInfo[i].classList.remove("campaign-container-slide");
}
```

and this works, but I'm just curious how come my first initial code (not this one above) doesn't work? how come using a counter works but not looping through it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could use nested `setTimeout` calls, or use [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp):

```js
var campaignInfo = document.querySelectorAll(".campaign-info-container");
var index = 0; // The index of the next `campaignInfo` div to update
var interval = setInterval(function() { // Create a new interval that fires every 500ms
  campaignInfo[index++].classList.add("campaign-container-slide");
  if (index === campaignInfo.length) { // The last div has been reached, so...
    clearInterval(interval); // Clear the interval using the reference
  }
}, 500);
```

```css
body { font-size: 2em;}
.campaign-info-container { background: #555; }
.campaign-container-slide { background: #eee; }
```

```html
<div class="campaign-info-container">One</div>
<div class="campaign-info-container">Two</div>
<div class="campaign-info-container">Three</div>
<div class="campaign-info-container">Four</div>
```

Comment: hey I have some comments. this works perfectly thank you. but I'm going to put my comments in my post as edits :)